# Is console.debug faster than console.log?

Tags: javascript

Here's what I tried:

```
const log = () => {
    console.time("Log");
    console.log("Test");
    console.timeEnd("Log");
}

const debug = () => {
    console.time("Debug");
    console.debug("Test");
    console.timeEnd("Debug");
}
```

When I run these results are as follows:

```
Test
VM406:4 Log: 0.06396484375 ms
Test
VM500:4 Debug: 0.059814453125 ms
```

And most of the time I see debug having a slight edge on log. Is it just co-incidence or debug is actually faster than log? And if so should we just stop using log at all cases and use debug instead?

Comment: Total coincidence.

Comment: Pointless question. If you're producing output for debugging purposes then performance is not the issue.

Comment: [Which is faster?](//ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant)

Comment: You're jumping to conclusions.  You're making a hasty generalization about performance from a terrible tournament of test cases.  Just because Adam beat Bob in a race doesn't mean you can predict the outcome of every future race between Adam and Bob.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the log level is handled as a string within the `console` object, and there is no reason to think that `debug` is faster than `log`.

The fact that trying to execute your code is likely to reproduce the output is  due to the fact that `log` is executed before `debug`, and I can suppose that most of the internal objects of `console` gets cached by the JavaScript engine. For this reason, the second execution will always be a bit faster than the first

```js
const log = () => {
    console.time("Log");
    console.log("Test");
    console.timeEnd("Log");
}

const debug = () => {
    console.time("Debug");
    console.debug("Test");
    console.timeEnd("Debug");
}

log();
debug();
```

```js
const log = () => {
    console.time("Log");
    console.log("Test");
    console.timeEnd("Log");
}

const debug = () => {
    console.time("Debug");
    console.debug("Test");
    console.timeEnd("Debug");
}

debug();
log();
```